# facet_zoom is zooming into different x axis values

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

Using this

**DATA**

```
df <- read.table(text = c("
Site    measured    simulated
site1   9.1 6.8
                          site2 163.1   128.1
                          site3 126 75.9
                          site4 741.2   843
                          site5 2215.1  1937.7
                          site6 283.6   423.4
                          site7 115.6   92.5
                          site8 12.1    15.3
                          site9 13.4    15.8
                          site10    475.7   296.1
                          site11    1   1.4
                          site12    84.5    131.9
                          site13    74.1    43.9
                          site14    19.2    33.3
                          site15    74.8    41.1
                          site16    287.8   366.9"), header =T)
```

and the script below

```
library(tidyr) 
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
df_reorder <-  transform(df, 
                         Site_reorder = reorder(Site, -measured))
df_long <- df_reorder %>% gather("id", "value", 2:3) 


ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Site_reorder, y = value, fill = id))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "black")) + 
  theme_bw()+
  facet_zoom(x = Site_reorder%in%c("site14", "site9", "site8", "site1", "site11"))+
  labs(x = "", y = " ")+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.90, 0.90), legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent"),
        legend.title = element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(angle=55, vjust=1,  hjust=1,size = 8))
```

I wanted the zoom to be for the last five sites (`site14`, `site9`, `site8`, `site1` and `site11`). Instead, it zoomed into the first five sites (`site5`, `site4`, `site10`, `site16`, and `site6`)

[image]

Any suggestions how to make the zoom for the last five sites will be appreciated?

Comment: Not a proper answer but try to make the x variable a factor. It *might* solve it...

Comment: @ThomasP85

Thanks for your time and suggestion. In my original data.frame, the x variable is factor. However, I still get the same problem.

Comment: What a shame - I think I know what the problem is and it is related to the discrete nature of your x-scale. Had hoped factorising it would solve it but it appears I need to think this through some more

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ggforce` only zoom on continous scale.

1- You can use `as.numeric` to convert levels to numeric,

2- then use `scale_x_continous` to print the sites names

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = as.numeric(Site_reorder), y = value, fill = id))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 0.7)+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "black")) + 
  theme_bw()+
  facet_zoom(xy = Site_reorder%in%c("site14", "site9", "site8", "site1", "site11"), horizontal=FALSE) + 
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 1:length(levels(df_long$Site_reorder)),
    label = levels(df_long$Site_reorder)
  )+
  labs(x = "", y = " ")+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.90, 0.90), legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent"),
        legend.title = element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_text(angle=55, vjust=1,  hjust=1,size = 8))
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your time and help. When it zooms for the last five sites, is there anyway to make the y_axis just from 0 to 100. The whole point is not to keep the original y axis because the values are so low for these sites.

Comment: @aelwan I think the shrink parameter of `facet_zoom` is supposed to do this, but it does not look like it is implemented yet: https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/blob/master/R/facet_zoom.R

Comment: @Chris
Thanks for your time and help

Comment: @HubertL
Using your nice answer, I found a line above zero across all sites in the top plot. Any idea why this line exist and how to remove it?

Comment: @aelwan This line is the upper y zoom boundary just add the parameter `show.area=FALSE` to hide it (it will hide the vertical one too)

Answer (score 0):

All credit goes to @HubertL, as this is based entirely off his solution. I have made it much more minimal so it can be easier to follow

```
df_reorder <-  transform(df, Site_reorder = reorder(Site, -measured))
df_long <- df_reorder %>% gather("id", "value", 2:3)

b <- df_long %>% 
  filter(id == "measured") %>% 
  select(-Site, -id) %>% as.tibble()


# b is just a minimal version of df_long
b

b %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(Site_reorder), y = value)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 0.7) +
  facet_zoom(xy = Site_reorder %in% c("site14", "site9", "site8", "site1", "site11"), horizontal=FALSE) + 
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = 1:length(levels(df_long$Site_reorder)),
    label = levels(df_long$Site_reorder)
  )
```